# Почему не работает matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Я пытаюсь построить простой график

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 2, 1, -1, -2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0])
plt.show()
```

получаю ошибку

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-548d62c4e367> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.plot([0, 2, 1, -1, -2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0])
      2 plt.show()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in __init__(self, figsize, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, linewidth, frameon, subplotpars, tight_layout, constrained_layout)
    346             frameon = rcParams['figure.frameon']
    347 
--> 348         if not np.isfinite(figsize).all() or (np.array(figsize) <= 0).any():
    349             raise ValueError('figure size must be positive finite not '
    350                              f'{figsize}')

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Везде такая ошибка, в google colab, jupyter notebook, pycharm

Comment: Вообще-то я проверил в `Google Colab` и там всё работает. Это точно весь код или вы до того что-то ещё делаете - например, ставите другие версии библиотек и т.п.? Или, например, задаёте какие-то параметры каким-то библиотекам перед исполнением этого кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код в таком виде, как вы его показали, прекрасно работает без ошибок. Я смог воспроизвести вашу ошибку только вот таким образом:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.array = [1,2,3] # <- Вместо метода np.array теперь у нас список!

plt.plot([0, 2, 1, -1, -2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0])
plt.show()
```

Проверьте остальной ваш код. У меня такое впечатление, что вы где-то ошиблись и вместо чего-то такого:

```
array = [1,2,3]
```

Или такого:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Написали:

```
np.array = [1,2,3]
```

Другой вариант - можно таким же образом сломать `np.isfinite`. Если же сломать другие функции, которые вызываются в этой же строке: `np.any` или `np.all`, то ошибка выйдет раньше, на другом фрагменте кода, так что скорее всего сломан именно `np.array`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Действительно был сломан np.array, исправил теперь летает!